# Reader view (Firefox) with confusing information

Tags: bug, developer-story

I opened my developer story in Firefox and enabled the reader view!

***A bit background***: I added a book written by Jon, Phil, Brad and Scott under "Recommended reading".

[image]

Comment: Do websites have any control over how the reader view is presented?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I appreciate that you are passionate about editing grammar, but did you really need to capitalize the e in `[enter image description here]`? You could have just as easily added a description of the image...

Comment: Thanks for the report. Facetiously, I'm reminded of :"Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*." "Don't *do* that."